# why does "gcloud dns records --zone="imaginout" edit" fail on OSX?

Tags: google-compute-engine

On OSX this brings up a vi editor. You can write the file and exit but it will still fail then output a long error stack. If you then do "echo $?" it outputs 1, indicating that vi returned an error status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that your ~/.vimrc is causing an error in the legacy vi editor. Try moving the .vimrc to another name then run the command again. Fixed it for me.